# Can a using directive be placed within the scope of an if-elseif-else block?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to change which namespace I use based on a user selection.  I have two nearly identical namespaces from the same API.  The methods within the namespaces have the same names.  If I could dynamically change the using directive, I wouldn't have to go back through the code and write the namespace in front of all the methods.  I want to write something like this:

```
if (radioIFC2X3.IsChecked == true)
{
    using Xbim.Ifc2x3.Kernel;
    using Xbim.Ifc2x3.Interfaces;
}
else
{
    using Xbim.Ifc4.Kernel;
    using Xbim.Ifc4.Interfaces;
}
```

I can't get this to work, so I thought you would maybe have some ideas.

Comment: no. `using` is a compile construct. you should look at the strategy design pattern

Comment: The closest you can get is using the if preprocessor directive, but this will be evaluated at compile time, and you won't be able to use your radio box.

Comment: This is code which no one wants to see(If it was possible), believe me

Comment: Put the namespaces in two entirely different classes in separate files: a `Ifc2x3Handler` and a `Ifc4Handler` which implement an interface or abstract base class. Use the user input to decide which class to create

Comment: maybe tell a bit more about what you're trying to achieve because this is an unusual use-case. I think you need to define  a shared interface between those classes/interfaces and use that instead.

Comment: Usually a namespace is something that has no real meaning at runtime, it's more or less an information about your code-structure and therefor primarily ment as compiler-information. Of course you can read that information at runtime. though. Having said this you should elaborate on why you want to switch a namespace. What do you want to *achieve* here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. "using namespaces" is a compile time thing. There is [#pragma if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) that can include code sections at compile time, but it would not help if you want to do something at runtime.

If you need to switch between implementations at runtime you need to use runtime constructs. Typically you should have something like

```
IKernel myKernel;
IInterface myInterfaces;
if (radioIFC2X3.IsChecked == true)
{
    myKernel= new Xbim.Ifc2x3.Kernel();
    myInterfaces= new Xbim.Ifc2x3.Interfaces();
}
else
{
    myKernel= new Xbim.Ifc4.Kernel();
    myInterfaces= new Xbim.Ifc4.Interfaces();
}
```

This would obviously require that you have actual objects you can switch out.

So if you have two nearly identical APIs a common solution is to provide thin wrappers around each that implement a common interface so they can actually be used interchangeably.